# How to put live streaming on the webpage?

Tags: python, html, live-streaming

I actually have a raspberry pi connected with robotic hand. Using BaseHTTPServer I connected Python and HTML. The intention is to make some buttons in the HTML so when you click on them, robot should move. That part is working great. But I want to put a live stream video next to the buttons in HTML, so when a user is on the webpage, he could watch what is he doing by pressing those buttons. I don't know if I should use some software like VLC, I have yawcam, but don't know how to livestream on my webpage, because it doesn't allow me to change the port number. Any advices?

Here is the basic HTML code for the buttons if it helps:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="control" method="post">
        <input name="button1" type="submit" value="left">
        <input name="button2" type="submit" value="right">
        <input name="button3" type="submit" value="up">
    </form> 
</body>
```

Comment: Perhaps you can try to stream video using WebRTC, as in [this](http://www.rs-online.com/designspark/electronics/blog/building-a-raspberry-pi-2-webrtc-camera) example.

Comment: Is the webcam connected to the raspberry pi?

Comment: @Wilhelm No, I am using the A4tech webcam connected to the laptop

Comment: @Sanjin_Rijeka Ok, try using [https://livestream.com/](https://livestream.com/). You can embed the livestream on your website.

Answer (score -2):

I would try to hook up with YouTube and insert the code they give you on your site. This would be very easy to do.